# Typing for object with similar key but different value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `human` object.

```
interface Human {
    ID: number;
    gender: string;
    hobbies?: string[];
}
```

I want to create a FormGroup with similar structure, how can I declare the typing for the FormGroup object?

```
interface HumanFormGroup {
    ID: FormControl,
    gender: FormControl,
    hobbies?: FormArray
}
```

I am creating this FormGroup manually, but hopping that I can do something like:

```
const humanForm: ValueAny<Human>
```

Is it possible?

P/S: *I asked this because there are `Partial<T>` modifier available, but not sure if there are any "ValueAny" modifier?*

Comment: Any array property should be mapped to `FormArray` and the rest to `FormControl`? How are nested object to be treated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to achieve this. The mapped type will map the properties of the original type and the conditional type will transform the original type of the property based on whether it is an array or not.

```
interface Human {
    ID: number;
    gender: string;
    hobbies?: string[];
}

type ValueAny<T> = {
  [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends any[] ? FormArray : FormControl 
}

type HumanFormGroup = ValueAny<Human>
// Will be quivalent to
// {
//     ID: FormControl,
//     gender: FormControl,
//     hobbies?: FormArray
// }
```

You can complicate the rules for the mapping further, but from your question these are the requirements I inferred.

Comment: Just to ask, are you familiar with Angular? To create a reactive form, we need to create a form structure, usually have similar structure to the underlying object. How do you specify the form object? Just wonder how most of the Angular user handle the typing issue? Declare manually, or just assign as `any`, or use your suggested approach?